How to include count column with filter to calculate percentage out of a total where total has different filters in Snowflake?
In warehouse database, there are multiple waves. Each wave has a certain number cartons that needs to be pulled from storage and delivered to the designated area where the items in that carton gets consumed. Database structure is task based. So a task number contains wave number, carton number, quantity in a carton, quantity consumed, task status. When the status is 0, the task is initiated and when status is 1 the carton is dropped at a place and quantity is consumed. So quantity in carton and quantity consumed is changed. Both column can be equal indicating that quantity in a carton is completely consumed and carton is destroyed. If not, then it goes to reserve. I want to find how many cases goes to reserve and their percentage per wave.
I am using following query:
SELECT wave, COUNT(carton) 
From Database 
WHERE task NOT LIKE '%K%' 
AND status = '1' 
AND quantity_inCarton != quantity_consumed 
GROUP BY wave

which produces
wave and no. of carton that are going to reserve
I want to include another column which shows the percentage of no. of cartons that are going to reserve out of total cartons( no. of total cartons in that wave can filtered by status=1 and task number not containing letter K)
Basically,
Filter 1 - task number not having letter K and status having number 1 gives the total number of cartons in that wave
Filter 2 - Filter 1 + quantity_inCarton != quantity_consumed gives the cases that are going to reserve.
Thank you.

Hi - please update your question to show 1) the DDL for the table 2) enough sample data to illustrate the possible use cases 3) the result you want to achieve based on your sample data. Please format code as code and data as tables

I typically use a CASE statement for things like this where you have the CASE that you want to use, if it matches THEN 1 ELSE 0.  Then, change the COUNT() to a SUM().

Thanks Mike, I have tried to do that using CASE statement but its including the ELSE result as well. That means its including the Carton that are not reserve.

I used the following query:   SELECT wave, COUNT(CASE WHEN status = '1' AND task NOT LIKE '%K%' AND  quantity_inCarton != quantity_consumed THEN carton ELSE '0' END), 100 * COUNT(CASE WHEN status = '1' AND task NOT LIKE '%K%' AND  quantity_inCarton != quantity_consumed THEN carton ELSE '0' END) / COUNT(CASE WHEN status = '1' AND task NOT LIKE '%K%' THEN carton ELSE '0' END
FROM Database
GROUP BY wave where its calculating the cases that are not in reserve. I tried to use SUM instead of COUNT, its giving me error due to 0

You misunderstood my comment.  The CASE statement should have the criterial that you need and if that criteria matches THEN 1 ELSE 0 END.  This basically creates a binary situation in your CASE output.  Either a 1 or a 0.  Do a SUM on that, and you'll get only the count of records where your condition is met.

Modifying your comment above with the solution that I was proposing.  I can't vouch for your logic in the case statement, but this is what I was getting at with the 1 and 0.  Also, I take the first expression for the numerator of your 2nd expression:
SELECT wave
     , SUM(CASE WHEN quantity_inCarton != quantity_consumed THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as exp1
     , 100 * exp1 / count(*)
FROM Database 
WHERE status = '1' AND task NOT LIKE '%K%'
GROUP BY wave;


Worked flawlessly!!! Thank you so much Mike.
